# How to manage Anaconda recipe with/without features

Tags: anaconda

I have written a conda recipe for which I'd like to have two versions: one with a feature and one without.

For the standard features (nomkl, debug, opt) you can just set the relevant environment variable (e.g. `FEATURE_NOMKL=1`) before calling conda build and it will automatically tweak the recipe and produce a build with the nomkl feature.

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#id1
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/environment-vars.html#environment-variables-to-set-build-features

How do I do this for a custom feature (one I have created myself). Is there any way to create an equivalent `FEATURE_MYCOOLFEATURE=1`? Or is there some way to do with with Jinja2 in the recipe?